# jquery get value by text (not selected) from dropdown

Tags: jquery

I would like to retrieve the value from a dropdown based on the text.

I know I could do this:

```
$('#RegionsFilterDropdown option:contains("item")').val()
```

However, this does not return an exact match.
For example, if the dropdown has options "item 1", "item 2", etc. then the above code will return more than 1 result, which is not what I want.

Any suggestions?

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method.

```
$('#RegionsFilterDropdown option').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === 'item';
}).val(); // returns value of the first matched element, if any
```

Comment: I banged my head against this for an hour trying to use this before realizing I had left off the "option" keyword.